# How to integrte Apache shiro with wso2 identity server

Tags: apache, shiro

I am new to Apache shiro I want to use Apache shiro as a security frame work for my spring mvc based web application. Currently I am using wso2 identity server for authentication purpose.

Comment: just google it's programming forms if you have ant try code and raise any error post here. we happy to help.

Comment: Have you tried anything, Venu? We try to discourage people looking for free work, or for help if they have not researched the problem thoroughly themselves.

Comment: Finally i got answer for my question from the link https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j/   Thanks for your reply @ Divyesh Kanzariya, @ halfer